# Why "string" is considered a "constant" in C language?

Tags: c, string, string-literals

Why "string" comes under the category of constants in C language ? even though it has no numerical value associated to it,unlike "character constant" which has a fixed integral value(ASCII value) associated to it.
In what reference a string is considered as a constant in C language ?

Comment: `even though it has no numerical value associated to it,`...what do you mean?

Comment: please clarify your question more

Comment: Or better, remove it and read a few first chapters to C for beginners book.  Clearly no prior research have been made.

Comment: By 'no numerical value associated to it' i mean that unlike character constant which has fixed integral value (ASCII value) associated to it, string constants have no such values associated to them..
I think i made this point pretty clear in the question description..

Comment: @LeśnyRumcajs Perhaps i am not as big a researcher as you are...
Take your own advice and do some prior research before inflicting your opinions on others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because it is a literal and it is supposed that literals are not mutable.

Consider an example

```
char *s = "Shubhamdubey2111";
char name[strlen( s ) + 1];

strcpy( name, s );

//...

*s = 'C';

//...

if ( strcmp( name, "Shubhamdubey2111" ) == 0  )
{
    // Oops! Do not trust your eyes!
}
```

Comment: ..Thanks for your answer !

Answer (score 0):

String literals are stored in initialized read only memory area of the process. This is the reason, the string literals cannot be modified.